# I need a special type of charts and don't know which chart plotting program support it

Tags: r, charts

I would need create a chart like the one on the picture. I don't want to draw it by hand, since I need more of them. I prefer R CRAN for drawing charts, but would do also any other programming or plotting program. If possible pdf or eps outputs are preferable. Does anybody have an idea, what type of chart, or which R (or other SW) package would support something like that?

[image: A chart with one dimension, and some additional lines]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Orange software package makes the charts.

https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/evaluation.cd.html